# C# Server side DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, storage

Please tell me, is it good to store DateTime, for example createtime of posts, on server in ticks?

```
DateTime.Ticks
```

Comment: What's wrong with just saving it as `DateTime`? And if you cannot, then perhaps saving it as string like in XML is better because there is no doubt when you parse it. Ticks is a number from an unknown point in time, what if this point is different in different cultures/servers/systems?

Comment: Whats wrong with storing in DateTime format? ticks would be harder to read if you are looking at data in the table

Comment: I do not want to store it in formatted string;) It is easy for me to manipulate with Int64 values;)

Comment: Your reason for not doing it the "correct" way is flawed ( you don't actually have a reason ) beyond "you don't want to do it" and "its easier it" of course its easier it is the way you know how to do it doesn't mean it the correct way.  Besides you asked if it was "good" and the simple answer its a poor and ineffective method.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no chance that anybody might ever want to view the stored data manually, or there is a particular requirement for that level of precision then fine. But generally, I don't like it, It's a pain to look at a days data in a database when the date is in some obscure format!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that? There is no penalty in storing it as regular DateTime. The better question you should ask yourself is how you would handle different timezones.

We store all dates in database as UTC, and do the appropriate conversion based on either user selected timezone or server timezone. Usually user selected, because it makes more sense for a user to handle times in his own timezone, but data will then be used by people in different timezones.

Answer (score 1):

Every modern database have `DATETIME`, `DATE` and/or `TIMESTAMP` datatypes, so there is no need for using an `Int64`.

But you could use `DateTime.Ticks` if you're saving data into a text file, for instance. Seems to be a good option in that case.